# sharing links via facebook opengraph api

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

Iam using the facebook opengeaph api to share links on facebook. Everything works fine but i couldnt control the title of the link being shared.

From the site i used all api params, but not even the image is getting posted ( and no info on  how to share for a specific group for that user).

/PROFILE_ID/links   Publish a link on the given profile

params->
link (encoded url), message (plain text), picture  (encoded url), name (plain text), caption (plain text) , description (plain text)

I populated every params as above but only the message is getting posted.

From what it looks its picking from the title of the web page as the share heading.

What i have is a desktop app, so i can use only the open graph rest api's. Is there a way to over come this and add my own message in the link heading ?

Answer (score 0):

You control the title of the link either by the og:title meta tag in the header or using the title tag in the header.  Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see if your pages you're linking to are correctly coding their HTML.

Comment: actually my app is a desktop app and dont have any control on the url. It will be posting the links for the user from the app. The org:title more sounds like a backend support for that particular url.

Comment: The og:title tag as well as other Open Graph tags are specified in the HTML of the link.  From your desktop app you cannot override those settings.  That would be a HUGE hole that spammers can abuse.